# Convert string vector with \n and k values into numeric with

Tags: r, string, split, type-conversion

I have a following vector. Where, we have `\n`, and `k` with numeric data, and `k` represent the **1000**.

```
v <- c("2.2K\n", "3\n", "1K\n", "1", "45", "5\n")

> v
> [1] "2.2K\n" "3\n"    "1K\n"   "1"      "45"     "5\n"
```

I need to convert the above vector into numeric vector as follows.

```
> v
 [1] "2200" "3"    "1000" "1"    "45"   "5"
```

Can anyone help me?

When I used the following command, I got solved the `\n`, but could not solve the `K`.

```
> as.numeric(v)
[1] NA  3 NA  1 45  5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `scan` + `gsub`

```
> as.numeric(scan(text = gsub("K", "e3", v), what = "", quiet = TRUE))
[1] 2200    3 1000    1   45    5
```

Answer (score 1):

Getting instead of deleting, replace possible powers of ten,

```
sub(r'{(\d\.?\d?\w?).*}', '\\1', v) |> 
  stringi::stri_replace_all_regex(pat=c('K', "M"), rep=paste(c('e3', 'e6'))) |>
  as.numeric()
# [1] 2200    3 1000    1   45    5
```

where pattern and replacement can be extended.